# Making site live on linode ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, xubuntu, apache2, dns

I am creating virtual host -- For that I have followed below Url details

[set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

I have created virtual host of name `raveesmake.com` also restarted apache server.

When I do `ping` command for `raveesmake.com` It displays packet data sent and received.

Now I want to make this site as live, So that anyone can access it by following `raveesmake.com`. But until and unless I add this in my local machin host file the site is not loading.

Did I need to add entry in DNS manager of linode? Before adding host did it check whether host has already buyed / available?

Comment: ping has no connection with webserver/http:80, ping works on IP level and will always respond. First check that your host is enabled by "sudo a2ensite vhostfile.com" This command creates softlink in /etc/sites-enabled so apache loads your config on reload/restart.

Comment: "sudo a2ensite vhostfile.com" displays message 'site already enabled'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add DNS entry to:

@.host.com IP
sub.host.com IP

Visiting browser will resolve your IP from hostname via DNS, and then send request via HTTP connection to your apache. Apache will check HOST header, like myhost.com or sub.host.com and will use associated virtual host loaded.

But it is completely irrelevant how you name your virtual host file. You only set **ServerName** and number of **ServerAlias** directives in it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host.com
    ServerAlias sub.host.com
    ServerAlias mirror.host.com
```

If apache receives an unknown HOST header (no ServerName associated from it among loaded virtual hosts), it will just use the first virtual host loaded, so if you have only one site, you can remove **ServerName** and **ServerAlias**, but disable "default" apache hosts (with hello-world pages):

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default default-ssl
```

For questions regarding apache2, use ServerFault stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

First create a `.conf` file located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/MyDomain.com.conf`.

> NOTE: REPLACE MyDomain.com with your domain name as wanted

Then type command `nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/MyDomain.com.conf` to edit the file and paste this codes to it:

```
# domain: MyDomain.com
# public: /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/public_html

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@MyDomain.com
  ServerName  MyDomain.com
  ServerAlias www.MyDomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> This is the default .conf file provided by Linode

Then type the command `a2dissite *default` to remove or disable the default apache2 and then type `a2ensite MyDomain.com.conf` to enable the site. Also, type `service apache2 reload` to make the site live.

> AGAIN, TAKE NOTE TO REPLACE MyDomain.com with your domain

You might want to add the DNS zones to linode and add a slave IP.

Step 1:
Login to Linode and Click `DNS Manager` and click `add a domain zone`. Then Provide these details:

[Guide Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDeQi.png)

Step 2:
Go to `Linodes>YourLinode###>Remote Access` and click `reverse DNS`. In then put your domain there and click `Look up`